After update to Ubuntu 24.04 hstr (history suggets box) does not work
After updating to Ubuntu 24.04 hstr (history suggets box) does not work. This is true on Ubuntu 24.04 and Kubuntu 24.04. The software is installed from the Ubuntu repositories.
History can be searched, but pressing enter does not select the entry, it only echoes it.
There is a related, albeit solved bug on this, on the upstream bugtracker.
I have appended the output of hstr --show-configuration to my .~/bashrc file as suggested in the related bug.

did you manage to solve the problem?

@SantaMonica Yes kind off. It works with the adjusted bashrc, when I invoke it with ctrl. + R, but not when I invoke it with the command hstr.

Unfortunately, I have the same thing...

This is due to new kernel in Ubuntu 20.04.
sysctl is used to modify kernel parameters at runtime.  The
parameters available are those listed under /proc/sys/.  Procfs
is required for sysctl support in Linux.  You can use sysctl to
both read and write sysctl data.
Run the following command to see if it solves the problem:
$ sudo sysctl -w dev.tty.legacy_tiocsti=1

If it works then you need to persist this so after reboot you don't have to type it again:
To ensure that this persists across system restarts on distros using recent systemd versions, create new conf file:
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'dev.tty.legacy_tiocsti=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/9999-legacy-tiocsti.conf"

Beware that they disabled it because of malicious scripts: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/LEGACY_TIOCSTI.html
I personally suggest you not to use that legacy option and switch to some other command history managers.

I will follow partly your suggestion and do not persist the change. I have in the meantime accustomed myself to using ctrl. + r. I can confirm that the command does solve the problem.
